# How to validate only one HTML control using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, backbone.js

i have a text box in which only positive value can be entered, if the negative value or zero is entered than remove the value and color the text box in red to indicate the user that he is not supposed to enter negative values.

this is what is my code :

```
    checkForNegativeValues : function(e){
                var intVal = e.currentTarget.value; 
                var nameOfControl = e.currentTarget.name;
// here i have to implement the logic but really don't know how to go about
                e.preventDefault();
                return true;
            }
```

i can get the value and control name but don't know how to validate, i have done for all the values in the form but the above control does not come under any control and comes in a div, this is because i am using backbone.marionette.

exactly some thing like this : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EB6ET/2/) but don't want to print the message but just mark the text box with red color.

so really helpless as how to go about.

Comment: You've mentioned the [tag:jquery-validate] plugin in your title but yet the content of the question, the jsFiddle, and the accepted answer have nothing to do with the plugin at all.  Please be more careful when writing your questions.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the example of JsFiddle, is this what you want to accomplish?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.abc').bind('keyup', function() {
        regex = /^[A-z0-9]+$/;
        if(!regex.test($(this).val())) {
            // append the color red to the background
            $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#f00');
        } else {
            // reset color to white
            $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#fff');            
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: +1 for the post, will check and come back to mark it as answer